# getting parent in self referential model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Based on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

I created a self join model called Category

```
rails g model Category name parent_id:integer
```

I altered the model category.rb as below

```
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: "Category"
end
```

Now in console I'm creating two records of Category as

```
a = Category.create(name: "Animal")
b = Category.create(name: "Dog")

a.sub_categories << b
a.save
```

Now

```
a.sub_categories # returns Dog
```

however

```
b.parent_category # returns nil
```

How do I get parent_category return the single parent record correctly?

Also if I do `b.parent_category = a`

I get the following error

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'parent_category_id'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the association parent_category.

There you have to specify the foreign key.

```
belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```